# select query to display data from multiple table in different rows with in same html table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.First table having two columns id and birds. Second table has two columns id and animals name. How to fetch this record using mysql and display it in a html single table in different rows.

[image: Birds table]

[image: Animals table]

[image: output table]

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this? If so please include your code

Comment: as the table field names are dfferent you need to use two different queries....

Comment: sorry i have no idea on how to get this. so i didnt have any code. @Epodax

Comment: How we can use two different queries to display data in a same table.It would be helpful if i can get the code @Nishant Solanki

Comment: Something like this might work: `SELECT a.id, a.Birds AS ResultData FROM tableA UNION SELECT b.id, b.Animals AS ResultData FROM tableB`.

Comment: Hi how to display individual columns in individual <td>  of the table. <td><?php echo '$columnname'?></td> @Gabor Bakos

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
select 
@r:=@r+1 as id , 
resultdata from 
(
  select birds as resultdata from birds 
  union all 
  select animals as resultdata from animals
)x,(select @r:=0)n;
```

Comment: I just want to display the result data in a html table. No need to save it in database. @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: This is not saving into the database, its selecting from the DB. You can run a loop and show the values into the html table.

Comment: Is it mysql query? I just want to display record from two tables in a single html table. I couldnt understant your code..can you please explain. @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: Yes its mysql query. Its doing a `union all` from the two tables and then using a user defined variable `@r` to increment it for each record to provide an `id` as you have shown in the desired result. If you are using PHP then connect to DB using the php code, then execute the above query and then finally do a loop and display the data into the table.

Comment: Can you please share the code to use it in php.whether i need to use while loop to execute this query? @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: Check this doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php, there is example of how to connect to db, then executing the query and finally loop  through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74232/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-abhik-chakraborty).